# Overflow Menu Items Text

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menuitem, menubar, android-styles

I went through enough samples and tried many combinations for entire two days, i have missed to grasp something. please correct me...

I Want to change the Color of Menu items Text present in overflow menu.

Thank you

my style file

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenuTheme</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MenuButtonTheme</item>
    </style>

    <!-- action bar -->
    <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/SmugeBlue</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitle</item>
    </style>
    <!-- action bar title -->
    <style name="ActionBarTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <!-- pop up menu background color -->
    <style name="PopupMenuTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/SmugeBlue</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">@style/MenuText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MenuText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MenuButtonTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/overflow_menu_button</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

[image]

---- updating with solution i found handy for my case

```
<style name="overflow_menu_text_color">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
....
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/overflow_menu_text_color</item>
.....
</style>
```

Comment: ayjay, i have update with solution i am using.